# ubuntu Server asus chromebox won't boot unless I have a hdmi display plugged in

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, hdmi

So I installed Ubuntu Server on my Asus Chromebox, all works great except I have a strange issue.

Ubuntu won't boot unless I have a hdmi display plugged in

I've tested this over and over. If I plug in the HDMI Display it boots and runs as expected, but since I wanted to run this as a server and SSH into the box, not if wont boot.

Is there a check I need to uncheck for the HDMI Display?

NOTE: I have command line access only, no gui

EDIT: Here is the installation process I'm following

- https://plus.google.com/115693545287597955633/posts/QsEE96RLJvV

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  There is no software solution that I can find.  What I did end up doing was buying the Fit PC Headless HDMI dongle.  It's about $15, and mimics an attached HDMI display.

http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/fit-headless/

Comment: ordered via amazon http://amzn.com/B00FLZXGJ6 will let you know if this works

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that either an HDMI or a USB keyboard (or in my case a spare Logitech unifying receiver) allow the system to boot.

When unplugged, the system is hard shut down instantly, no acpi suspend or anything like that. A little bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:
I had the same issue (different hardware, though). This is what worked for me:

1. Edit the grub config file:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

2. Uncomment (remove the # at the beginning of) the following line:

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Be sure to save the file using Ctrl-O then Enter.

3. Update grub:

```bash
sudo update-grub
```

4. Reboot.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/v0ff1r/ubuntu_2204_server_wont_boot_without_hdmi_plugged